# InnerText у HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#

Почему используя `InnerText` я из элемента получаю:

`&lt;`, если в коде Html `<`

`&gt;`, если в коде Html `>`.

Что ещё может измениться ?

Или как получить значения которые в коде Html (который вижу в панели разработчика Chrome) без каких либо изменений

Comment: https://html5book.ru/specsimvoly-html/

Comment: @trydex ни о чём не говорит. Почему меняются не все спец.символы в InnerText ?

Comment: Не знаю.Если бы вы объяснили что конкретно парсите, и что именно получаете, то было бы яснее.

Comment: @trydex Парсю строку, в которой может появиться абсолютно любой символ.

Comment: `как получить`...`без каких либо изменений` - не как. А вообще, используйте [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx), в самом HAP вроде был аналог, назывался он вроде `DeEntitize` (сами найдете). И да, если не ошибаюсь, такой HTML вы получаете при загрузке его с сайта, сам HAP лишь преобразует то, что имеет в удобный нам формат.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо ! Это помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для избежания интерпретации браузером этих символов как обычную разметку а не простой текст, их кодируют при передаче.

Для кодирования и декодирования текста HtmlAgilityPack предоставляет утилиту HtmlEntity. Для декодирования используйте метод DeEntitize.

```
string actual = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(node.InnerHtml);
```